# Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle): "URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"

Tags: r, csv, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to read a csv file using below code.

df = s3read_using(FUN= read.csv, bucket="my-bucket-name",object="object.csv")

While doing this I am getting the below error

*Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle): "URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"*

Answer (score 0):

#### Reproducing the error (looks like a bug)

I can reproduce the error, but I cannot explain it:

```r
s3read_using(FUN = readRDS, object = "pfd.RDS", bucket = "collidr-api")
# Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : 
#   Moved Permanently (HTTP 301)  
           
s3read_using(FUN = readRDS, object = "pfd.RDS", bucket = "collidr-api", region = "ap-southeast-2")
# Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : 
#   Moved Permanently (HTTP 301)
```

#### An alternative

An alternative way to read in your data is like so (run the code below and it should work - you'll just have to replace bucket/file/region with your own values, and use `read.csv()` instead of `readRDS()`.

```r
bucket <- "collidr-api"
file <- "pfd.RDS"
region <- "ap-southeast-2"

s3location <- paste0("https://", bucket, ".s3-", region, ".amazonaws.com/", file)

readRDS(url(s3location))

#     package_names                     function_names
# 1              A3                                  a
# 2              A3                                 a3
# 3              A3                         A3-package
# 4              A3                            a3.base
# 5              A3                     a3.gen.default

# Data reads in successfully!
```

#### Please note

I noticed I got the same error message when I attempted to read a file that I didn't have permission to read. So that's another possibility. A very quick way of testing is to see if you can access the file directly in the browser, using the file's url (i.e. copy/paste the `s3location` variable above into your browser's address bar - if it downloads the file, there's no reason R should be able to do the same, but if it says access denied, then R will not be able to read that file without credentials for the bucket).

Answer (score 0):

My input bucket name was like abc_res. Due to the naming convention I was getting the above error. I changed the bucket name as abc-res and error got resolved.